# Can I update the spacy's Entity Linking knowledge base after training?

Tags: spacy-3, spacy-transformers, entity-linking

Let's suppose I have successfully trained an Entity Linking model, and it is working just fine. But, eventually, I'm going to update some aliases of the knowledge base. Just some aliases not the description nor new entities.

I know that spacy has a method to do so which is: `kb.add_alias(alias="Emerson", entities=qids, probabilities=probs)`. But, what if I have to do that after the training process? Should I re-run everything, or updating the KB will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to try it and see.

If you're just adding new aliases, it really depends on how much they overlap with existing aliases. If there's no overlap it won't make any difference, but if there is overlap that could have resulted in different evaluations in training, which could modify the model. Whether those differences are significant or not is hard to say.

Comment: Hi @polm23, thanks for that. The aliais are just aliais, so it should work. Thank you again.